# Why are we so concerned with the source of creation?

Tags: metaphysics

Background story: A friend and I came to the conclusion that if "nothing is impossible," then everything/something is possible and thus everything comes from something.

This led us to question **why do we (humans) even care if there's a source? Why are so concerned with the origin our creation?**

Does it come down to easing our inescapable fear of death? Is it to understand ourselves at a deeper level/find our life's purpose? Is it to seek direction/find peace?

I am interested in the community's insights (And sorry if this question has been asked a million times in a million different ways, but I thought our backstory was relevant to the question). Looking forward to hearing your thoughtful responses.

Comment: there was a question about why assume that everything has a cause (re god) let me see if i can find it

Comment: apologies could not find. good luck with your question

Comment: Unless and until we have a workable theory of origins philosophy will be a muddle of clashing conjectures, as we see from the literature.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Asking "community's insights" into why we care is kind of soliciting personal opinions which is off-topic here. Could you rephrase the question to make it more objectively answerable, say from a point of view of some philosophical school. Also, the first sentence is odd, if everything is possible then nothing, in particular, is also possible, and something may come both from something else or from nothing.

Comment: In some sense, you could ask: why are we concerned with anything? Most science deals with things that don't really affect us directly or even indirectly. I think it's just our natural curiosity, or more sinisterly, the fact we have too much free time to think since we've made surviving fairly easy.

Comment: Causality is pretty much the ultimate axiom in physics (and therefore all other physical sciences),  therefore something being 'uncaused' is a great worry to us,  because it threatens our whole understanding of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that even all educated people are concerned with the origin of their creation.  But some people are.

When we are awake our mind always wander here and there to fulfill something without knowing what it actually is. All the materials we get can satisfy us  up to a limited period only.  But the wandering continues without an end because with the help of present elements/factors the nature can create/is creating myriads of combinations.  This wandering will stop only by the knowledge of our self.  Great men who realized it said so and the new generation follows them.  Those who tried to test it no longer didn't need to ask a counter question...because they were FULLY SATISFIED with it.  This truth  is deeply rooted in us also.

> Does it come down to easing our inescapable fear of death?

Certainly.

> Is it to understand ourselves at a deeper level/find our life's
>   purpose?

You need not used the term -- 'deeper level'.  You can simply use--'to know our real nature'.  Or to realize the divinity in ourselves.

It is for reaching the highest level that we can attain with our human body.  Thus our life's purpose will be fulfilled...not for finding (our life's purpose).

> Is it to seek direction/find peace?

**It is for the liberation from all bondages FOR EVER**.  One can also say so--'to find peace'; because it is also possible.

Some people might say that it is possible with one or two peg.  But this won't answer whether that peace can be retained FOR EVER.

Why?

Isn't it sure that you feel you are born here and are experiencing the happiness and sorrows of this mundane world?

When you realize the origin of your creation you become like a roasted seed.  And so you won't 'sprout again'....I mean, you won't take another birth. You will also know whether the usage 'origin of your creation' is actually right or wrong.

If you don't know the origin or your creation you won't be able to know even about your past birth or at least about the truth whether your soul is immutable.

See this (Sri Ramakrishna parable):

> A salt doll wanted to measure the ocean’s depth. It wanted to be the
>   first to tell how deep it was. But the moment it got into the water,
>   it melted.

Please read [the words of Vivekananda](http://greenmesg.org/swami_vivekananda_sayings_quotes/human_being-real_nature_of_human_being.php)